# In illustrator file, how to print/report swatch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

I have a pattern in Adobe Illustrator and I can go to Swatch and see the CMYK code for all the colors used - how do I print this set in a report or on printer so that I can share the color codes with others.

Comment: I don't think there's any direct method for outputting the Swatch Panel. You'd have to script something.

Comment: Thanks - new to this world, do you know where I can find the script?

Comment: I think @Scott means that it would need to be scripted, not that he has a script in mind.

Answer (score 1):

http://js4ai.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/generate-color-legend-from-swatches.html

This link will show you how to list every swatch in your swatch panel and include the CMYK break down.

Also check out:

http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/

```
*(Render Swatch Legend v1.1)*
```

Once you save the Java code (.jsx or .js) you can use FILE > SCRIPTS in ILLUSTRATOR to run them.

To keep them in the FILE > SCRIPTS menu copy them to:

/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC 2014/Presets.localized/en_GB/Scripts/

*(en_GB is for the English Language version, your language might be different)*

and when you restart Illustrator they will be in the menu.